# How can I reuse ng-grid on lots of pages?

Tags: angularjs

I have lots of pages with grid, so I need to write lots of configuration(js codes) in each of the controller, and if I have two grids on one page, I need to write two almost same code in one controller(Just like the example below).

Did I do the right thing?

Thanks!

--- add -----

like this Paging Example in [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.filterOptions = {
    filterText: "",
    useExternalFilter: true
}; 
$scope.totalServerItems = 0;
$scope.pagingOptions = {
    pageSizes: [250, 500, 1000],
    pageSize: 250,
    currentPage: 1
};  
$scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){  
    var pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
    $scope.myData = pagedData;
    $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
    if (!$scope.$$phase) {
        $scope.$apply();
    }
};
$scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var data;
        if (searchText) {
            var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
            $http.get('jsonFiles/largeLoad.json').success(function (largeLoad) {        
                data = largeLoad.filter(function(item) {
                    return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                });
                $scope.setPagingData(data,page,pageSize);
            });            
        } else {
            $http.get('jsonFiles/largeLoad.json').success(function (largeLoad) {
                $scope.setPagingData(largeLoad,page,pageSize);
            });
        }
    }, 100);
};

$scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);

$scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage) {
      $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
    }
}, true);
$scope.$watch('filterOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
      $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
    }
}, true);

$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    enablePaging: true,
    showFooter: true,
    totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
    pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
    filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions
};
```

});

Comment: Please show some of your repetitive code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use services to organize and share code across your app.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services